# rake aborted! Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter on rails db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

Gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '5.0.1'
gem 'bcrypt',       '3.1.11'
gem 'puma',         '3.4.0'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.4.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.6'
gem 'unicorn'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.12'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

migration fails when running rake db:migrate.
tried setting the environment variable to development using RAILS_ENV=development still it fails. i am using postgres in production as heroku provides postgres.Both the gem file and database.yml is given.

Edit:
I tried cloning repo into another machine and tried it was working fine.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, the problem was with my local machine as I recently installed Postgres without brew .  Once i uninstalled rhat and restarted the migration was successful.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

And then this:

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Then, your adapter in production is `sqlite3`. See how you set it in default and then didn't set it in production?

Also, this bit:

```
production:
  ...
  database: db/production.sqlite3 << right here
```

Seems like it's going to give you heart ache.

You realize, naturally, that it is **not recommended** to use sqlite in development and postgresql in production. It says so right on the Heroku web site. Because, well, you're going to have exactly the sorts of nightmares you're having right now. (There are more technical explanations on the Heroku site and around the Innerwebs. Read them. It's good for the soul.)

Unless you like that sort of thing.

*** EDIT ***

Sorry, I was moving too fast. It looks like you're having the problem locally when running `rake db:migrate`?

In any case, still not a great idea to use different DBs in development and production.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the database config for development explicitly. Looks like the database.yml is not aligned correctly.

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: your_db
  host: 127.0.0.1
  pool: 5
  username: your_db_username
  password: your_db_password
```

Comment: am using sqlite database for development

Comment: @Aditya if you satisfy with my ans then make it correct and vote up